# How to fetch column names of a table using HQL and populate in a list?

Tags: db2, hql

I want to fetch column names of a table using HQL and populate the same in a list?..Please guide. I am using IBM DB2 database.

Comment: HQL uses entities, their fields and associations. If you want table column names, use JDBC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested, but you can query the DB2 catalog in order to get the metadata. If you execute the equivalent in HQL, it should work

```
select colname
from syscat.columns
where tabschema like 'MYSCHEMA%' and tabname = 'MYTABLE'
order by colno
```